# list_head not recognized when compiling linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, list

I am compiling a modfied version of the kernel that has a C program I made. I'm new to this, and I can't get rid of this error:

error: unknown type name ‘list_head’; did you mean ‘rcu_head'?

Here are the lines leading up to the line with the error:

```
//directives
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/sched/task.h>
#include <asm-generic/barrier.h>
#include <linux/resource.h>

#define set_task_state(tsk, state_value)            \
    do {                            \
        (tsk)->task_state_change = _THIS_IP_;       \
        smp_store_mb((tsk)->state, (state_value));      \
    } while (0)

#define PROC_NUM 50
#define MILSEC_GAP 2

*(delta_entry) get_delta_entry(int num, *linked_list);
int get_delta_time(list_head *linked_list, delta_entry *de, int max);
```

I know `list.h` includes `types.h`, which defines list_head. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at `types.h`, it seems to me that the problem is this: `list_head` is the name of a structure tag, not a type. So you need to write 
`struct list_head ...` rather than simply `list_head ...`. In other words, the function prototype should read

```
int get_delta_time(struct list_head *linked_list, delta_entry *de, int max);
```

and whenever you want a variable, you need to declare it as

```
struct list_head head;
head.next = ...
```

See 
http://c-faq.com/struct/typedef.html and
http://c-faq.com/struct/impltypedef.html

Comment: Here is the `struct list_head` definition: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/types.h#L186 that OP talk about. This is the right answer!